# regexFilter just filter Strings and not the cell. How can i filter the cell and not the string above?

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I'm implementing a UI for Configuring DataPoints in AUTOSAR models. I'm using Java Swing for the implementation.

My problem is that I have a `JTable` (customized) which the 4th column has in each cell a combobox inside.

I use also a filter in the top for a better workflow because it can happen that in a single `AUTOSAR` model it can appear over 1000 DataPoints. This is why a filter option is needed. The problem here is that the regexFilter just filters the Strings of the cells, and not the order of the combobox-cells. Here my code: (part of it)

```
private void enableSorting(JTable table, Object o) {
   DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
   if (model == null)
             return;

   TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>();
   table.setRowSorter(sorter);
   sorter.setModel(model);
   // Filter zeigt nur Reihen in denen  enthalten ist                               
   if (o != null) {
             rfs.add(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + o.toString(), 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6));
             rf = RowFilter.andFilter(rfs);
             sorter.setRowFilter(rf);
   } 
   else {
             sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(""));
   }

 }
```

How can I sort also the combobox-column with the combination of the regexfilter?